# Modifying number of digits in Rmarkdown tables (kable)

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, kable, kableextra

I have a `dataframe` with different number of `digits`. For example:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(0.0003, 4, 23.22, 50000))
```

When I use `knitr::kable` I get this table:

```
knitr::kable(df)

|         a|
|---------:|
| 3.000e-04|
| 4.000e+00|
| 2.322e+01|
| 5.000e+04|
```

The issue is that I want all of the values in `c(0.0003, 4, 23.22, 50000)` to appear the way they are (e.g. with no scientific notation).

I have tried using:

```
options(scipen = 1000)
```

This gets rid of the scientific notation, but adds a new problem:

```
knitr::kable(df)

|          a|
|----------:|
|     0.0003|
|     4.0000|
|    23.2200|
| 50000.0000|
```

Here, I do not want e.g. `4` to appear as `4.0000`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this, transforming them into `character`:

```
df = data.frame(a = as.character(c(0.0003, 4, 23.22, 50000)))
```

Comment: It also occurred to me and I already tried it. It does work! But I feel like this would not be an efficient and recommended way of solving the problem. My table is very large (e.g. a few `A4` pages long). But I am still voting +1 to your answer as this is indeed useful! :)

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to display numbers with varying number of decimals, you may need to turn the numbers to characters for that.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(b = case_when(a %% 1 != 0 ~ formatC(a, 4), 
                       TRUE ~ as.character(a)))

#           a      b
#1     0.0003 0.0003
#2     4.0000      4
#3    23.2200  23.22
#4 50000.0000  50000
```

Comment: By "It is not possible to display numbers with varying number of decimals" do you mean in `dataframe`s or both in `dataframe`s and `kable`/`table`s in `Rmakdown`? Doing it for `R` `dataframe` may not be possible due to technical/efficient programming purposes but I feel like for displaying `table`s in `Rmarkdown` documents there should be a way. At least for scientific publications written in `Rmarkdown` it would not make sense to display numbers with unnecessary extra `digits`. I may be wrong here.

Comment: I meant in general in R but I think you are right for display purposes there must be special provision in them to specify number of digits to be displayed. Although I usually prefer to "prepare" the data beforehand.